# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: with chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using a code to scrape some data from google maps. I seem to have problems with the last function that I define below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from parsel import Selector
import re
import time
import sys
from PlacesVisualiser import *

from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import os

googleAcceptButtonClicked = False

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
os.chmod(service.path, 755)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
action = ActionChains(driver)


def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    """
    This function checks if the element specified by the xpath is present at the website.
    It is used to check if any places are available in the Google Maps searching results' menu.

    :param xpath: the xpath of searched element
    :return: boolean value corresponding to the existence of the searched element
    """
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


def scrollDownLeftMenuOnGoogleMaps(counter, waitingTime):
    """
    This function is responsible for scrolling down the menu visible at the left.
    It is used while searching for places at Google Maps. It allows seeing more places relevant for the search value.

    :param counter: number of scrolls down
    :param waitingTime: waiting time until next scroll (new results are loaded)
    """
    menu_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a'

    if check_exists_by_xpath(menu_xpath):
        for i in range(counter):
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, waitingTime)
            menu_left = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, menu_xpath)))
            menu_left.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)


def searchForPlace(url, typeOfPlace):
    """
    This function is responsible for searching a place of specific type at specific location with set zoom.
    All information about searching are contained in the URL.

    :param url: path which is inserted into browser
    :param typeOfPlace: type of place searched in Google Maps
    :return: dictionary containing places found using this URL
    """
    global googleAcceptButtonClicked
    driver.get(url)

    # only at the first page click the "accept all" ("zaakceptuj wszystko") button
    if not googleAcceptButtonClicked:
        clickAcceptAllButton()

    # scroll down left menu
    scrollDownLeftMenuOnGoogleMaps(counter=3, waitingTime=2)

    # get the source code of the page
    page_content = driver.page_source
    response = Selector(page_content)

    placesResults = []
    # save the search results into a dictionary
    for el in response.xpath('//div[contains(@aria-label, "Results for")]/div/div[./a]'):
        placesResults.append({
            'link': el.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first(''),
            'title': el.xpath('./a/@aria-label').extract_first(''),
            'type': typeOfPlace
        })

    return placesResults


def clickAcceptAllButton():
    """
    This function is responsible for clicking "accept all" button at the first page opened after initialization of
    the webdriver.
    """
    global googleAcceptButtonClicked
    button_path = '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form[2]/div/div/button'
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    button = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_path)))
    button.click()
    googleAcceptButtonClicked = True
```

I am using the web driver but getting the following error when it gets to the clickAcceptAllButton function. Do you know how to fix the bug? I have tried increasing the waiting time or maximizing the screen but it doesn't work.

```
(base) jdtorres@SIE-C02G50GLML86 Google-Maps-Scraper-master % /Users/jdtorres/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/jdtorres/Downloads/Google-Map
s-Scraper-master/MainScraper.py
/Users/jdtorres/Downloads/Google-Maps-Scraper-master/MainScraper.py:21: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
['bar', 'cinema', 'office']
total number of points to check:175
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdtorres/Downloads/Google-Maps-Scraper-master/MainScraper.py", line 183, in <module>
    new_places = searchForPlace(url, typeOfPlace)
  File "/Users/jdtorres/Downloads/Google-Maps-Scraper-master/MainScraper.py", line 72, in searchForPlace
    clickAcceptAllButton()
  File "/Users/jdtorres/Downloads/Google-Maps-Scraper-master/MainScraper.py", line 101, in clickAcceptAllButton
    button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_path)))
  File "/Users/jdtorres/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010d740598 chromedriver + 4973976
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010d737913 chromedriver + 4938003
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010d2f4cd6 chromedriver + 470230
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010d3382ff chromedriver + 746239
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010d338591 chromedriver + 746897
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010d37a384 chromedriver + 1016708
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010d35c9ed chromedriver + 895469
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010d377856 chromedriver + 1005654
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010d35c793 chromedriver + 894867
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010d32a21f chromedriver + 688671
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010d32b56e chromedriver + 693614
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010d6fabb7 chromedriver + 4688823
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010d6ffa51 chromedriver + 4708945
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010d70640f chromedriver + 4736015
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010d70091a chromedriver + 4712730
15  chromedriver                        0x000000010d6d387c chromedriver + 4528252
16  chromedriver                        0x000000010d71ff28 chromedriver + 4841256
17  chromedriver                        0x000000010d7200a7 chromedriver + 4841639
18  chromedriver                        0x000000010d73128f chromedriver + 4911759
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff816b111d3 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff816b0cbd3 thread_start + 15
```

Comment: there could be many reasons for this error, and people will only be able to solve your problem if you share the code snippets that you tried. So please edit the post and add your code.

Comment: thanks @AjeetVerma I added some more details with the code and how the function is defined

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you made, I concluded that it takes more time to load or the button is not visible on the screen, so you need to wait for some time until the button gets rendered in your page, or if it's available on the screen, you need to scroll to it and click it, so this below function should work fine for you.

```
# use python version: 3.8 or above
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import os


service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
os.chmod(service.path, 755)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
action = ActionChains(driver)

def find(xpath: str, sec: int = 30):
    WebDriverWait(driver, sec).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    try:
        action.move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)).perform()
    finally:
        return driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)

path_obj = find(xpath="//*[@id='button_to_click']", sec = 10)
path_obj.click()
```

Comment: thanks so much @VigneshKannan, I added some of the code to give more details. It's not working for me to increase the waiting time

Comment: then instead of the WebDriverWait line add
    import time
    time.sleep(sec)
it waits even if the element appears on the screen.